# GooglemapV3 infowindow closeclick event is not getting fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, infowindow

The below code is being used to show infowindow over Google maps on click of markers. But due to some reasons 'closeclick' event for info windows are not working. Earlier it was working though, but due to more complexity further in requirements like infowindow object needs to be reopened as it is after refreshing the maps on Ajax calls. So maps keep refreshing after one minute and the requirement is that, infowindows should remain open if not closed at Ajax calls.

We also draw poly lines on maps and we also open an infowindow on every point it draws over the Google map and the same requirement is also applicable for infowindows objects as above.

```
        $(".mainDiv").each(function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click');
    if (PlayBackDevices.indexOf(removeSpaces($(this).find(".deviceid").html()).trim()) > -1) {
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage($(this).find(".imagepath").html());
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).find(".latitude").html(), $(this).find(".longitude").html());
            var beachMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: $(this).find(".deviceName").html().trim(),
                labelContent: $(this).find(".deviceName").html().trim()
            });
            markers.push(beachMarker);
            var imgPath = trailImagePath + trailColor.trim() + ".png";
            var beachMarkerTemp = new RichMarker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                flat: true,
                anchor: RichMarkerPosition.BOTTOM//,
            });
            i = i + 1;
            oms.addListener('click', function (beachMarker) {
                infoWindow.close();
                infoWindowDevicePoints.length = 0;
                if (deviceName.trim() == beachMarker.title.trim()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "/Home/CommonLevel2Information",
                        data: { DeviceId: 101 },
                        async: true,
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            result = createInfo('', result + '<br/><a href="' + linkToNextLevel + '" title="Click to view DeviceDetail"><%=GlanceWeb.Resources.Level2.Level2.RegMrDtl%>...</a>', deviceId);
                            beachMarker.desc = result;
                            if (result.toString().indexOf("divMainSnap") > 0) {
                                var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
                                    $(".gm-style-iw").css("width", "400px !important;");
                                    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: beachMarker.desc, maxWidth: 400 });
                                    infoWindow.open(map, beachMarker);
                                    position = beachMarker.position;// iw.getPosition();
                                    $(".gm-style-iw").each(function () {
                                        if ($(this).find("div.divFirstSnap").length) {
                                            $(this).removeClass("wiThouImage");
                                            $(this).css("max-width", "none");
                                        }
                                    })
                                    clearInterval(checkExist);
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                            else {
                                var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
                                    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: beachMarker.desc, maxWidth: 200 });
                                    infoWindow.open(map, beachMarker);
                                    position = beachMarker.position;// iw.getPosition();
                                    if ($(".gm-style-iw").length > 0) {
                                        $(".gm-style-iw").removeAttr("width");
                                        $(".gm-style-iw").each(function () {
                                            if (!$(this).find("div.divFirstSnap").length) {
                                                $(this).addClass("wiThouImage");
                                            }
                                        })

                                        clearInterval(checkExist);
                                    }

                                }, 1000);
                            }

                            //Following section is used to manage device pop-ups after ajax 
                            for (var i = 0; i < infoWindowDevicePoints.length; i++) {
                                infoWindowDevicePoints[i].latLng
                                if (position == infoWindowDevicePoints[i].latLng)
                                    isExist = false;
                            }

                            if (isExist) {
                                infoWindowDevicePoints.push({
                                    latLng: beachMarker.position,
                                    popUpData: beachMarker.desc
                                });
                            }
                            UnBlockGlanceScreen();
                        }
                    });
                    }
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "closeclick", function () {
                debugger;

                var that = this;
                that.getposition()
                var latlnginfo = that.getposition();
                infowindowdevicepoints = $.grep(infowindowdevicepoints, function (value) {
                    return value.latlng != latlnginfo;
                });
            });

                oms.addListener('spiderfy', function () {
                    infoWindow.close();
                    infoWindowDevicePoints.length = 0;
                });
                oms.addMarker(beachMarker);

            }

        });


});
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: You add 'closeclick' event listeners in 5 different places. Do any of them get executed? Your code is fairly complex, over 400 lines long. Can you simplify it to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question?

Comment: Hello Duncan, I have shorten the lines of code to make more clear to understand. Infowindow opens up but the closeclick event does not get fire. I was trying keeping the events in different place in order to check whether it works there not but in vain. Also there are many other places from where the Infowindow pops up in different conditions.

Comment: You create the infowindow inside your ajax success handler. Did you define it as a global variable already?  At the point where you attach the closeclick event handler, what do you get if you just do `console.log(infoWindow)`?

Comment: Yes, infowindow defines as global variable . I have tried doing same console.log(infoWindow) gives nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're only creating the infoWindow in response to the ajax request. However when you add the `closeclick` event listener, that probably executes before the ajax response has happened.

You need to move this block:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, "closeclick", function() {
    debugger;

    var that = this;
    that.getposition()
    var latlnginfo = that.getposition();
    infowindowdevicepoints = $.grep(infowindowdevicepoints, function(value) {
        return value.latlng != latlnginfo;
    });
});
```

... inside this block, after the if-else statement which creates the infoWindow

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(result) {
            // add a call to the event listener here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Duncan, right place where it worked is under            `var checkExist = setInterval(function () {});`. Working now. Thanks again.